# How to make dynamic database structure for Commodities in SQL?

Tags: sql

I want to create a database for online shops, my database has "Commodity" and type of "Commodities". Before that I want to create its dynamic I create 2 tables for `Commodity` and `CommodityType`.

For example, "Mobile" category has many details like:

- cpu
- ram
- internal storage
- battery
- etc.

and external "Hard Category" has details like:

- capacity
- waterfall
- armor
- hasAdaper
- etc.

I want the admin of my website to be able to add new a category that may have new properties; then add related "Commodity" to it.

My problem is how to design my database and tables?

I think that when the admin adds a new category, the system must make a new table with properties that the admin defines for this category.

Is that how to do it, or can you suggest a better way?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Is this the problem - I don't have rights to create/edit the tables on DB. Only the admin can do that. How do I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for an [Entity-Attribute-Value Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model)

Answer (score 1):

I see two approaches :

1. Define a specialized table with the custom fields when the new product type is created.
2. Have a table CustomProperties, where you list the properties, a table TypeProperties, where you save which type has which property, and finally a table PropertyValues, where you store the values, each value a line.